# Grouping by and getting multiple rows to one cell separated by commas

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that title is ambigious and I know that there are similiar questions here. I looked and could not made anything work exactly as I need.

I need to Group By ReportNumber and those sharing one category add to one cell.

My DB:

```
  ID  |      CategorySymbol    |     ReportNumber   |   NumberInCategory    

   1             A                       31                101
   2             B                       31                107
   3             C                       31                121
   4             A                       32                191
   5             A                       33                165
   6             B                       32                156
   7             C                       32                127
   8             A                       31                166
   9             B                       31                177
```

Desired result:

```
  ReporNumber  |         CategoryA         |       CategoryB        |     CategoryC       

   31                      **101,166**                   **107,177**                121
   32                      191                       156                    127
   33                      165                       NULL                   NULL
```

One of many different attempts:

```
select ReportNumber,
  CategoryFirst, CategorySecond, CategoryThird, CategoryFourth
from
(
  select NumberInCategory, Report.value('(/Report/@ReportNumber)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS ReportNumber,
    'Category' + cast(CategorySymbol as varchar(10)) CategorySymbol
  from dbo.ReportDB t
) d
pivot
(
    max(NumberInCategory)
  for CategorySymbol in (CategoryFirst, CategorySecond, CategoryThird, CategoryFourth)
) piv;
```

My result:

```
  ReporNumber  |         CategoryA         |       CategoryB        |     CategoryC       

   31                      **166**                       **177**                    121
   32                      191                       156                    127
   33                      165                       NULL                   NULL
```

It is obvious why the result is how it is - max(NumberInCategory). The only question is how do I get to make a query that selects Number based on the CategorySymbol in for loop. I tried doing funtions that return one result like STUFF or simple SELECT but couldn't do them properly. It does not let me replace max(NumberInCategory).

E.g. something like that:

```
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(NumberInCategory AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()], Report.value('(/Report/@ReportNumber)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS ReportNumber
         FROM ReportDB
         WHERE ReportNumber = t.ReportNumber
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_Output
```

Comment: Your query does not conform to table schema

Comment: @Amit I think I fixed it now

Comment: Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Cannot find either column "Report" or the user-defined function or aggregate "Report.value", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: I guess you are right in that sense. I think if you would replace "Report.value(...) AS ReportNumber" with just "ReportNumber".
It just in my DB Report is a xml field that has a field ReportNumber

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) before `pivot()`:

```
;with t as (
  select 
      NumberInCategory
    , Report.value('(/Report/@ReportNumber)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS ReportNumber
    , CategorySymbol
  from dbo.ReportDB
)
select ReportNumber, CategoryA, CategoryB, CategoryC
from (
  select
      t.ReportNumber
    , CategorySymbol = 'Category'+convert(varchar(10),t.CategorySymbol)
    , NumberInCategory = stuff((
        select ', '+convert(varchar(13),i.NumberInCategory)
        from t i
        where i.ReportNumber = t.ReportNumber
          and i.CategorySymbol = t.CategorySymbol
        order by i.NumberInCategory
        for xml path (''), type).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
      ,1,2,'')
  from t
  group by t.ReportNumber, t.CategorySymbol
  ) s
  pivot (max(NumberInCategory)
    for CategorySymbol in (CategoryA, CategoryB, CategoryC)
  ) piv;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/OSAZ69656

returns:

```
+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| ReportNumber | CategoryA | CategoryB | CategoryC |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|           31 | 101, 166  | 107, 177  | 121       |
|           32 | 191       | 156       | 127       |
|           33 | 165       | NULL      | NULL      |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: it works almost perfect. The problem is that have this damn ReportNumber in xml fild Report. I access this like this: "Report.value('(/Report/@ReportNumber)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS ReportNumber" If I use it like that with your answer it gives me errors because there is no such column in my table. Should i create new table with added columnReportNumber just for this query?

Comment: @cantdoanything33 I added a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) before the query to extract your xml value from your xml column prior to concatenating and pivoting. Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: Thank you! I modified it, added some data and works great. Next step is to be able to write something like this from the beginnig to the end by myself. I know it might be a bit offtopic but could you point me where to go from here (I am after Pluralsight and Udemy courses) ?

Comment: @cantdoanything33 I do not have any experience those sites, but I am sure there are some great ones. 
What I would recommend: 
Sign up for the newsletter at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/ and read it every day;
Join your local sql server user group and virtual user groups http://www.pass.org/;
Free video of sessions at https://groupby.org/ and https://sqlbits.com/;
Presentations by Louis Davidson http://www.drsql.org/presentations;
Books like SQL Server MVP Deep Dives, and books by Itzik Ben-Gan or Louis Davidson;
Blogs by Aaron Bertrand, Brent Ozar, Paul White, and sqlskills.com.

Comment: @cantdoanything33 It looks like the team at SqlSkills has some pluralsight courses: https://www.sqlskills.com/sql-server-training/online-training/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different flavor...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    CategorySymbol CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    ReportNumber int NOT NULL,
    NumberInCategory INT NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TestData(ID, CategorySymbol, ReportNumber, NumberInCategory) VALUES
    (1, 'A', 31, 101),
    (2, 'B', 31, 107),
    (3, 'C', 31, 121),
    (4, 'A', 32, 191),
    (5, 'A', 33, 165),
    (6, 'B', 32, 156),
    (7, 'C', 32, 127),
    (8, 'A', 31, 166),
    (9, 'B', 31, 177);

-- SELECT * FROM #TestData td;

--==================================================================================

SELECT 
    td1.ReportNumber,
    CategoryA = MAX(CASE WHEN td1.CategorySymbol = 'A' THEN STUFF(c.CSV, 1, 1, '') END),
    CategoryB = MAX(CASE WHEN td1.CategorySymbol = 'B' THEN STUFF(c.CSV, 1, 1, '') END),
    CategoryC = MAX(CASE WHEN td1.CategorySymbol = 'C' THEN STUFF(c.CSV, 1, 1, '') END)
FROM
    #TestData td1
    CROSS APPLY (
                (SELECT 
                    CONCAT(',', td2.NumberInCategory)
                 FROM
                    #TestData td2
                WHERE 
                    td1.CategorySymbol = td2.CategorySymbol
                    AND td1.ReportNumber = td2.ReportNumber
                FOR XML PATH(''))
                ) c (CSV)
GROUP BY
    td1.ReportNumber;
```

Results...

```
ReportNumber CategoryA  CategoryB  CategoryC
------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
31           101,166    107,177    121
32           191        156        127
33           165        NULL       NULL
```

Comment: Great Answer! The problem is that have this damn ReportNumber in xml field Report. I access it like this: "Report.value('(/Report/@ReportNumber)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS ReportNumber.  I can't make the above work properly with that field. Could you maybe could look at that?
It is simple xml structure <Report ReportNumber="123" >...</...

Comment: In that case, parse the 3 necessary columns from the  XML into a #TempTable. From there, either of the two posted solutions should work.